# Is there anyway directly query the oracle db with where clause instead of filtering on complete dataframe in spark-sql 2.x

Tags: apache-spark, datastax

I am using spark-sql.2.3.1 and I am connecting to oracleDB to fetch the dataframe

```
Code : >'    ora_df
                      .option("schema",schema)
                      .option("partitionColumn", partitionColumn)
                      .option("dbtable", query)
                      .load()
       > '
```

> Issue :
>               I would like to filter the table with date. So is there anyway to pass the query with dynamically build where clause?

Comment: @Alex ott sir can you tell if I can query using where clause directly on oracleDb instead of filtering the resultant dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is customary:

```
 val dataframe_mysql_4 = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, s"""(select DISTINCT type from family where type like '${val1}' ) f """, connectionProperties)
```

Set up you r connection string and then with variable setting of val1 you can add a where clause that uses this value. Note the f.

Comment: Started q :  """( select * from MODEL_VALS WHERE DATA_DATE ='${colVal}'  ) T """ 
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)

Comment: why did you put " f """ at the end of the query ? what does it mean here ?

Comment: You could put e as well. But need an alias.

Comment: if I have two queries alias should be different or same also fine ?  In earlier query DATA_DATE ='${colVal}'  ...this is not being parsed to respetive string value of "colVal" , what did i do wrong here ?

Comment: Hard for me to comment on the date. Did you fill it (correctly)? ORACLE has certain approaches here. The 2 queries can use the same alias - I know it's a bit odd but that's just protocol. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337722/ora-01741-illegal-zero-length-identifier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182994/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-user3252097).